# screen coordinates interfere with the bar at the bottom of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm learning about android game development and have made a few small games. The problem I encounter is that when I draw an object at the bottom of my screen it is hidden behind the bar at the bottom.

[image]

For example I made a simple pong game, but my paddle is hidden behind the bar.
I retrieve the screen size as follows:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int x = size.x;
    int y = size.y;
```

My paddle is a rectF object with bottom coordinate equal to y.
Other little games i made encouter the same problem. Every time i draw an object at the bottom of the screen with the canvas and paint classes it interferes with the bar.

How can i solve this? Is there a way to retrieve the coordinates of that bar?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

Answer (score 0):

According to specifications, DisplayMetrics is probably what you should use instead of Display:

> public void getMetrics (DisplayMetrics outMetrics)
>   Gets display metrics that describe the size and density of this display. The size returned by this method does not necessarily represent the actual raw size (native resolution) of the display.

You could use this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;
```

Comment: Tried it, still the same result... The height coordinate includes the bar.